# model interaction between words for a sentiment analysis task

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression, sentiment-analysis, feature-interaction

I am wondering what is the most appropriate way to model the interaction between two words/variables in a language model for a sentiment analysis task. For example, in the following dataset:

```
You didn't solve my problem,NEU
I never made that purchase,NEU
You never solve my problems,NEG
```

The words "solve" and "never", in isolation, doesn't have a negative sentiment. But, when they appear together, they do. Formally speaking: assuming we have a feature «solve» that takes the value 0 when the word «solve» is absent, and 1 when the word is present, and another feature «never» with the same logic: the difference in the probability of Y=NEG between «solve»=0 and «solve»=1 is different when «never»=0 and «never»=1.
But a basic logistic regression (using, for example, `sklearn`), wouldn't be able to handle this kind of situation (it doesn't add interaction terms).

Comment: It depends on how you teach the models those objectives. The semantic rules can be learned thanks to attention mechanisms that define if a specific structure is NEG or NEU. Do you want to train a new model or reuse a new one?

Comment: Thank you @NicolasMartin. That's what I was wondering: which machine learning or deep learning architectures can be used to model the interaction between words. I want to train a model from scratch. It is a more experimental exercise. What could I try?

Comment: You should train a Bert model from scratch (check online guides or chatgpt)